# C# statement inside using block returns null

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and curious about next example:

Imagine we have such code:

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
    {
        deflateStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

And:

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
    {
        deflateStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The first example works as expected, while the latter just returns null.
How does `using` work internally?
I expect it to work like simple try/finally, but it seems it closes `MemoryStream` before invoking `toArray`.

On the other hand following code works as expected too, which brings even more mysteriousness:

```
private static byte[] Decompress(byte[] payload)
{
   using(var inputStream = new MemoryStream(payload))
   using(var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
   using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
   {
       deflateStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
       return outputStream.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: On your compress example, it is the disposal / flush of the deflate stream that is relevant, not the memory stream - that is why the second example returns null, you're returning the content of the memory stream before the deflate stream is flushed to it.

Comment: @steve16351 You have to close or dispose the stream, `DeflateStream.Flush` is basically a no-op.

Comment: `How does using work internally?` https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgBgARwIwDoCSB5A3AWAChEUMd0BhAewFsAHAJwFMBnFgSyoDsDiBmFACYkFJAG8ijdgDcAhgBcmpCEmABPRQG0AuiNqNWLABTqtugCYLZASiITCSR0jkMkVAK7y6npAF4kXEwA7kgAskw0VAxqAMryzLI0Rta8TijIRi5I5kwAZgA2CkxxCTR+AcFIACJ5hYolTIlGHl6eADR69MxsnFwAMkzSTPnoAGKyLIqT1rYOTvZpaTkFRQ2J6ADqDOyKRpbysh0IHfuy6ANcAObyABYpRGkAvg9OcADsbp7e8ugAKlQAQQYDFkamSvGehEeQA

Comment: @steve16351 I think you could turn this into an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @steve16351 Thanks. Feel free to post it as question, please.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is because for many `Stream` implementations, data that is written to the stream is not necessarily immediately acted on and pushed to its final destination. That might be for reasons of performance, such as a `FileStream` buffering up data in memory to write before physically writing to disk, or because the final output is not known until all the input data is available - such as a cryptographic stream where the output has to be a certain size and the end of the data may have to be padded. So, unless you are certain of the implementation, you can only assume all the data is available once the `Stream` is disposed or closed.

So in your first example,

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
    {
        deflateStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

Here the using statement disposes the `DeflateStream` which triggers it to send all the output to the `MemoryStream`. You call `ToArray()` on the `MemoryStream`, and it has the output as you would expect.

However, in your second example:

```
using (var output = new MemoryStream())
using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
{
    deflateStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

You are returning the content of the `MemoryStream` *before* `DeflateStream` is disposed, because the call is inside the second `using` block. At that point, `DeflateStream` has not had the `Dispose` call which triggers it to write its compressed data to the output stream, and so the `MemoryStream` is empty and you get a null result.

For your final example, `CopyTo` generally reads from one stream into a buffer, and then writes that buffer to the target stream until all the input data is read. So in the case, it works because data is still written to the `MemoryStream` before you return the result.

Answer (score -1):

You are understanding incorrectly the usage of the using statement, in the first example works as intended because you never disposed the MemoryStream. While in the second statement you are disposing the MemoryStream as soon as you are ending the DeflateStream

First of all, you should always dispose your streams as soon as they re done, i had messy results when not disposing them correctly.

Now, I ll try to explain where you are wrong and how to correct each of those 2 examples which would be the same for the third one (its like the second)

First example (solution):

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
    {
        deflateStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    var ret = output.ToArray();
    output.Dispose();
    return ret;
}
```

Second example (solution) equivalent to the above code:

```
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] ret;
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
      {
         deflateStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
         ret = output.ToArray();
      }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

in the second example i added the brackets so you understand what you are really doing with the using, its the same as if you are writting a one line action for a true or false in an if statement.

Comment: I would gladly wanna hear the feedback on the person that gave me a down vote because as far as i know this is the answer, and im even providing the person that asked the question with detailed explanation on the problem